# Why it gives me an error Argument must not be null?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragment, android-adapter

Please explain why it gives me an error  Argument must not be null? Maybe this is due to the fact that the photos should be displayed in a fragment and not in an activity.Can you explain please,i really can't figure it out.I think the problem is in this line of code userImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.RoundedLayoutUsers); but what exactly is wrong...

```
public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.UserViewHolder> {
private List<UserModel> list;
private Context mActivity;
private DatabaseReference rootReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
private String currentUserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

public UserAdapter(Context mActivity, List<UserModel> list) {
    this.list = list;
    this.mActivity = mActivity;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new UserViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_user,parent,false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
    UserModel user = list.get(position);
    //    Picasso.get().load(user.urlImage).into(holder.userImage);
    Glide.with(mActivity)
            .load(user.urlImage)
            .circleCrop()
            .into(holder.userImage);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    RoundedImageView userImage;

    TextView loginName;
    RatingBar ratingBar;

    public UserViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        userImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.RoundedLayoutUsers);

    }
}
}
```

here is the complete error code

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.chatden, PID: 9146
java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null
    at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:29)
    at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:23)
    at com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder.into(RequestBuilder.java:669)
    at com.example.chatden.adapter.UserAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UserAdapter.java:60)
    at com.example.chatden.adapter.UserAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UserAdapter.java:32)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LayoutState.next(LayoutState.java:98)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.fill(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:1607)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:683)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:605)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16659)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5452)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16659)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5452)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1775)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16659)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5452)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16659)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5452)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16659)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5452)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16659)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5452)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16659)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5452)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16659)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5452)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2706)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16659)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5452)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2216)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1124)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6072)
```

I wonder what if you run through Picasso then writes Target must not be null.

Comment: Because no view by that name exists in that view.  That's the only reason that function ever returns null.  Make sure you're using the right name and layout file.

Comment: Checked it.Id coincided...

Comment: I wonder what if you run through Picasso then writes Target must not be null.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `user.urlImage` is null. Debug the line of `UserModel user = list.get(position);` and inspect the user object.

Comment: How about `holder.userImage` ?

Comment: I think that everything works there too, the fact is that before that I was displaying the necessary tape with pictures from the database. Then the markup file was RelativeLayout and there was ImageView and everything worked good.But then I looked at the tutorial on com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView.He sticks instead RelativeLayout but they don't write in it ImageView.So I deleted mine.And in  onBindViewHolder i refer to id com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView As shown in the tutorial...

I wonder what if you run through Picasso then writes Target must not be null.